# How to update an Access table from queries

Tags: sql, count

To give a bit of context, there are these tables, **Game purchases**, **Game Transfers** and **Game activations**, where each have entries of a user, a game and a date of the specific action, with game transfers having a sender and a receiver user.

What I'm trying to do is have another table, called **inventory**, which will have entries **automatically updated** from the entries in the others, adding 1 to the value of an entry which specifies a user, a product and what quantity they have (and 0-quantity ones are hidden) if they are the buyer of the game in the **game purchases** table or the receiver in the **game transfers** table, or remove 1 from the quantity if they are the activator in the **game activations** table, or sender in the **game transfers** table. I plan to do this by counting the number of entries in these other tables, taking note of the combinations of user x product for the specific entry in the inventory and tallying the ones of the same type in the manner described. I manage to count the number of combinations in one table quite successfully, with a simple select and group by, but I can't manage to make them add up after that. How should my code look like to make this work and can it even work in Access?

And sorry if the question is already answered.

Comment: Access 2010 or any other version ?

Comment: 2010 version, or at least a newer one

Comment: You can use event-driven Data Macros which are similar to triggers.More details at [ms-access-trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623440/ms-access-trigger).This will be a better solution than counting and tallying with other table.