# Looking for a way to trigger a script when our Biometric inserts a new row

Tags: php, node.js, ms-access

In our office we have a biometric scanner that inserts into a MS Access Database running on one of our local servers. That's just how the thing is built and we can't get into it to modify how it works.

We created a web-based attendance system that needs the Biometric information since the online system allows users to time in via the online form or the biometric scanner.

Our current setup right now is that every 1 minute, the local server runs a scheduled task in the scheduler to push the data to our remote server (this task is a PHP script) where the online app is hosted.

That slight delay isn't very nice and we'd like the data from the local server to sync right away with our online app, since sometimes the local server just dies and we don't know why.

TL;DR:
Is there a way to monitor any changes to the local server (MS Access) that will send the changes to our remote server using NodeJS or PHP? If there are other solutions available, those will be welcome as well.

The local server is running, a driver called ZK Attendance Manager with an MS Access Database. The remote server uses MySQL.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even in SQL Server I try and avoid triggers if at all possible. Access does not have them per se... but here is an article I previously found in looking it up... because sometimes you just need the functionality. Granted I've never used a Data Macro but from what it says it may be able to help you in your situation.
Read: 
[MS Access trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623440/ms-access-trigger)