# Microsoft Access AfterUpdate Macros

Tags: ms-access

I'm designing a **"HOSTEL"** database in MS Access 2016 to track the Check Out date in "Booking" table and make automatic changes in the bed status in "Bed" table. So, if `[Booking].[CheckOut]` is equal to the current date, the system automatically changes the value of `[Bed].[BedStatus]` from *"Occupied"* or *"Reserved"* to *"Available"*.
I'm ready to hear any suggestions. Thank You very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you really want to make changes depending on **table** changes or based on changes you make via a form / module?

Comment: I want to see changes in automatic way. I mean when the Check Out date is equal to current date, the status of bed is changed to "Available" without any interference from anybody's side. In this way I exclude human factor of "possible forgetting" to switch the status to desired one (in my case "Available") in manual mode.

Comment: Just to be sure, this needs to be on the table side? Why not just implement this on your form? i.e. if the checkout date is past today, display the field bedstatus as available?

Otherwise maybe a data macro helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623440/ms-access-trigger Data macros can be triggered on events, i.e. on update / on delete. Unfortunately besides that Access doesn't support database triggers i.e. "at a certain date change one field to something different"