# MS access After update - new record in another tab

Tags: ms-access, vba

I Try to find the way, how to make AfterUpdate event - to create new record in another (no updated) Table.

I mean, I've got 2 tables:

**T_Prices** : *product_ID*, Prices for *m2* and *package*.

**T_AllPrices** incl. *PID, m2, pcg, date*.

I try to make event, query or sth, that create new record in T_AllPrices, after I update / change prices in table T_Prices, manually or via query. The New record should include NEW PRICES, so I don't need to use [old].[m2]...

I hope this img will explain it better than I did.

[image: img with explanation]

Thank you all for help

Comment: AFAIK, there is no AFTER TRIGGER feature in Access where you can capture an Update on the T_Prices table like you might in SQL Server. If you are using Access to edit your T_Prices table, perhaps you can use an After Event on one of the form controls.  Is this your question?

Comment: what version of access are you using? keyword is table triggers.

Answer (score 0):

search for Table triggers/ data Macro if you are using MS Access >=2010.

A sample answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25722579/1684486

Comment: I saw this "builder" ... I'm using MS Access 2016 so I use :After Update: to create T_Price_History (for example) - so there will be prices that I replace. Not Current Price. And That's what I need. 
There is such a thing I tried  - [old].[field] - but I need to replace [old] with sth like [new] or...idk...     I know that [new] will not work. :(

Comment: if you have tried, please post screens and what you tried. will be helpful to understandand  help you.

Comment: I'll check it when I get home from work. But probably I remove my efforts cuz it wasn't working. anyway, I used :After Update: and I try to replace [old]  like:

SetField 
Name  Field1_T_AllPrices
•Value = [field1]   -  without [old]   or 
•Value = now().[field1] - but now() probably works only with time / date
•Value = [field1].[field1] - the same one - 2 times from T_Prices...   
- nothing from this worked

Comment: Well the only thing that works is created History table (PZC on image) from original Table (P) - by using :AFTER UPDATE: . So it records numbers that was just replaced. It doesn't get current numbers. :-/  [link](https://imgur.com/mu1ylLU)

Answer (score -1):

You should never operate on the tables directly.

Use a *form* (in Datasheetview if you prefer) bound to the T_Prices.

Then use the *AfterUpdate* event of the form to create the new record in the other table.

Comment: "You should never operate on the tables directly."
 - I don't, I Just try to prepare the most easiest ways to creating records. so Is there any chance to create Query that Update - Change prices in T_Pricess, second Query that Create new record in table T_AllPrices, and then create form, with fields - m2 | pcg, and GO! button, which starts both queries? - I think this is much more difficult way .. but is it possible?

Comment: *"You should never operate on the tables directly"* Why ?

Comment: _The most easy way_ is to use a form. Tables are not intended for user operation.

Comment: I try to avoid calculating with tables, but I just cannot this time. It's hidden calculation that user don't see. but after opening query Q_MMA, he/she should see - Min  - Minimal price for m2 / pcg, Max Price, and average Price. All those calculations have to operate with all prices in history incl. newest one

Comment: That's what a query is for. In the table you should record the Id, price, and date from which that price is valid. Then you can retrieve the current price as well as the price at any earlier date.