# Automatically import new data from a MS Access database into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, automation

I have an Access 2003 database that data is inserted into throughout the day and I want to convert to a SQL Server database. There are many different instruments and processes that insert into the Access database, so it would take a lot of modification to change all of them to insert into SQL Server.

I know Microsoft has [a tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-access-accesstosql?view=sql-server-2017) to convert an Access database to a SQL Server one, but as far as I can tell, it can't be run automatically and it wouldn't be able to just import the new data since the last "merge" (please correct me if I am wrong)

What would be the best way to go about this problem? Maybe some sort of script?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of ms-access are you using? If it is at least 2010 or above you can create event-driven macros which function similar to a `trigger` in SQL server, this post may help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623440/ms-access-trigger), with those you could just insert data automatically from Access to your SQL Server

Comment: I'm using Access 2003

Comment: Maybe this tool would work for your case, "SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (AccessToSQL)" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-access-accesstosql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The problem with Microsoft's SSMA is that I don't see a way to automatically run the migration. From what I can tell it is used as a one-time conversion from Access to SQL

Comment: I was looking to see if I could find anything on running SSMA as a SQL Agent Job but I have not found anything as of yet. Can you read the Access table data from within SQL Server? If so, you could schedule a SQL Agent Job to run every night at a specific time and do an `INSERT` from a `SELECT` of Access

Comment: On the Access side, are there only Inserts? Or Updates/Deletes as well? -- And on the SQL Server side, will this database be read-only? Or will there be Inserts/Updates/Deletes too? -- Depending on the answers, things may be very complicated or rather trivial.

Comment: @Andre There are only inserts on the Access side, and the SQL will be read-only

Answer (score 5):

> There are only inserts on the Access side, and the SQL will be read-only

Then I would do this:

- Link the SQL Server tables into the Access database
- Run INSERT queries to copy the new data into the server tables. This assumes that all tables have primary keys.

The queries would e.g. look like this (air code):

```
INSERT INTO dbo_Customers
SELECT src.* 
FROM Customers AS src LEFT JOIN dbo_Customers AS tgt 
  ON src.ID = tgt.ID
WHERE tgt.ID IS NULL
```

`Customers` is the local table, `dbo_Customers` the server table.

The query selects all records from `Customers` that don't exist in `dbo_Customers`.

---

Since several other processes access the original database, it's probably best to set up a new Access database, link both the original and the Server tables, and run the INSERT queries in the new db. You don't want any code running in the "data" db.

It can be automated e.g. with a `Form_Timer` procedure.

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for. Thank you!