# refresh sql table with access table link

Tags: sql, ms-access, dsn

I created a link between an access database table to a SQL table by first exporting the entire access DB table and then by linking both. My intention is to get my SQL table refreshed with new values as and when my access database values change. How can I do this? Please help

Comment: What is an *SQL table*? MS Access uses the SQL language. Please tag the backend RDBMS: Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623440/ms-access-trigger

Comment: by SQL table, i meant a table in SQL Database

Comment: What is an *SQL Database*? SQL is a language adopted by most relational dataabses. It is akin as saying an English book. Access is an SQL database that maintains its own tables!