# Join Query on a “blank” Table - Need it to add when updating

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a `table1` with `x1` as key and stuff, then `table2` with `x2` as key and columns (ex: `dataA`, `dataB`, `dataC`) but `t2` have no records in it. `t1` and `t2` are joined by `x1` and `x2`.

I want it to, when I add something to any data, it to create a new line in `t2` with `x2` = `x1` and `dataA`, `B` or `C` with whatever I'm doing.

t1_____________t2

x1 _ t1.a _ t1.b _ t2.dataA _ t2.dataB _ t2.dataC

1 __ a ___ b ____ updating

t2 from having no records to

x2 _ dataA

1 __ updating

Comment: An example of data you currently have an example of expected results would help. What have you tried so far?

Comment: In other words *"When I insert into `table1` I would like a record inserted into `table2`"*. In most RDBMS this would be handled by a `trigger`. That is some script that is executed upon an action taking place in the database (like when you insert into `table1` it performs the action of inserting into `table2` using the same key). Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623440/ms-access-trigger) specifically [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25722579/2221001) on "Event driven macros" for how to create something like a `trigger` in MS Access.

Comment: Unrelated, you can use a site like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to make formatted tables for here on Stackoverflow. Just paste the output from that site into you question, highlight it all, and click the `{}` button at the top to preserve the format.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataMacro (aka Named Macro) and run it in the AfterInsert event on table x1 ([Menu Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDfD4.png))

The [Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2dp1.png) takes the new values in x1 and creates a record in x2 based on the fields you choose to use.

If you want to create a record for any update to x1, run a DataMacro in x1's AfterUpdate event. For example, if you are creating a log table called x2, you can access the old value in the macro for the x1 field using [Old].[field1] and you can access the new value (after the update) using [field1].