# Track changes (Create Audit Trail) while Editing Access database via Excel Userform

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am shifting to an Access database from Excel database to support multi-user entry.
I have excel Userforms which I am using to add and update Access database stored in sharepoint. I want to track all the changes in this database in a seperate table in the database to maintain an Audit trail for review purpose later.

This is an example Update function:

```
Sub Edit()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
        Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
        Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
        Dim dbPath As String
        Dim qry As String
        
     
        dbPath = "Share-point UNC path"
        
        cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";Jet OLEDB:Database"
        
        Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset
    
        qry = "SELECT * FROM FileNumbers WHERE [File_Number]= '" & EditForm.txtFile.Value & "'"
        
        rst.Open qry, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
        
        
        With rst
            .Fields("Archival_id").Value , EditForm.txtArchival.Value
            .Fields("Remarks").Value , EditForm.txtRemarks.Value
            .Fields("Retention Category").Value , EditForm.cmbRetention.Value
            .Update
        End With
        
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub
```

I want to track the changes in a seperate table which will look like this:

[image]

I can record Edited by, edit date and time, and the new values easily. I am having trouble in recording the old values and Parameters edited, which will be the Column Name in the File Numbers table

I also have a Log Changes function I was using when I was using Excel as database. This is the function:

```
Sub LogChanges(c As Range, vNew)
    With c
        sep = IIf(Len(titles) > 0, "; ", "") 'need a separator?
        If .Value <> vNew Then
            'track the changes
            titles = titles & sep & .Parent.Cells(1, .Column).Value 'column titles in Row1
            oldValues = oldValues & sep & ValueOrBlank(.Value)  'track old value
            newValues = newValues & sep & ValueOrBlank(vNew)    'track new value
            .Value = vNew                                       'update the cell
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function ValueOrBlank(v)
    ValueOrBlank = IIf(Len(v) > 0, v, "[blank]")
End Function
```

And then I was using the variables, oldValues, newValues, and titles to update the Audit trail sheet. I can't seem to implement this method here. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't implement things like Audit Trails on the front-end side (Userform or data objects). Those things belong to the back-end (Database). The front-end shouldn't care about facts how data is stored and if there is an audit trail.

On a database, you usually use a mechanism called *trigger*. A trigger is a kind of script that runs in case of a database event, eg an insert or an update command. Within such a trigger, you can implement the audit trail logic.

Now in Access, the name for those mechanism is not trigger, but *data macro*, but basically it's the same idea. I found this [answer about trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25722579/7599798)  in Access on SO which basically links to the official docu from Microsoft about [data macros](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200?ocmsassetid=ha010378170&correlationid=99299f6d-89fa-4055-baea-7fca15efd7c8&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: The problem with this way is that I am using  Excel userform instead of Access form to fill the database. I couldn't find any solution for tracking changes while using Userform to edit the database

Comment: That's the idea: In your front end, you issue  Update or Insert-statements. Those are not really executed on the client side, they are send as commands to the back end (Excel is not really updating the database, it sends a request to update to Access).  There, the trigger should fire so that beside the update you request, also additionally actions are performed - in your case writing the old and new values in an audit trail table.

Comment: I found a great article for this: https://scottgem.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/audit-trail-using-data-macros-2/
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: For some reason the AfterUpdate event is not being triggered when I am updating the database from VBA userform. But it works perfectly fine when tI change something manually in the database. Can you help?