# Trying to track changes in my MS Access Database

Tags: ms-access

I have a table set up to track when people place an order (Order_Tbl). I duplicated the table that I call my order_change_log and added a date/time field (default value set to now). I have a one to many relationship between the orderID and order_change_logID. The idea is that before update, I want the existing data to be inserted into the change log table. I went into the before update field and made the following statement:

CurrentDB.Execute “INSERT into Order_Change_Log SELECT * FROM Order_Tbl WHERE ChangeLog_ID =“”” & Me.ID & “”””

I keep getting “Invalid Outside Procedure” and I’m getting frustrated… Not sure what I’m doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called a trigger.  In access a table's triggers can be accessed and created from the table's design mode via [Create Data Macros] on the ribbon.  You are pretty much forced to use the macro language to create the trigger.
As an aside it looks like you are setting the default date in Order_Change_Log.  Leave that default blank as it is not needed here and in many other cases leads to bugs.
In this case we will be using the after-update macro.  The Before-Update values are available using [Old]
For an older example of a trigger happening after Delete see [MS Access trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623440/ms-access-trigger)

Example Table and Relationships:

[image]

After Update Trigger Macro:
[image]

Use the ribbon to save the macro and you are done.  change some values in the Order_Tbl then refresh or open the Order_Change_Log table to see the results