How can I automatically update the data in a record when I create a new record in a different table?
I have a table called Member. In this table is a field called NoOfLessonsBooked. When a Member has booked a total of 10 lessons, they should get a free lesson. I have another table called Booking, which stores details of all the bookings that have been made. Every booking includes a MemberId for the member who made the booking. I want the NoOfLessonsField to go up by 1 for every record in booking that includes the MemberID of a member. So every time MemberID 1 makes a booking, I would like MemberID 1's record in the member table to update it's NoOfLessonsBooked by 1.
Here are the 2 tables in question:
Member Table



MemberID
MemberForename
MemberSurname
MemberDOB
MemberAddress
MemberTown
MamberPostCode
MemberTelNo
MemberEmail
MemberMedCert
NoOfLessonsBooked




1
Reece
Agnew
29-Oct-06
SomeWhere 1
SomeTown
ZX81 5PK
0101 323656
ReeceA@email.com
No
1


2
John
Hanna
23-Dec-74
SomeWhere 2
SomeTown
ZX80 3CL
102 323656
JohnH@email.com
No
1


3
Arthur
Marston
13-Nov-58
SomeWhere 3
SomeTown
ZY1 2BC
103 323656
ArthurM@email.com
Yes
0


4
Bradley
Stone
09-Aug-01
SomeWhere 4
SomeTown
ZX81 5PK
104 323656
BradleyS@email.com
No
0


5
Dawn
Pearson
08-Mar-02
SomeWhere 5
SomeTown
ZX80 3CL
105 323656
DawnP@email.com
No
0


6
Freya
Adams
27-Feb-03
SomeWhere 6
SomeTown
ZY1 2BC
106 323656
FreyaA@email.com
No
1


7
Aurora
Bell
24-May-12
SomeWhere 7
SomeTown
ZX81 5PK
107 323656
AuroraB@email.com
No
2


8
Mike
Graham
12-Dec-56
SomeWhere 8
SomeTown
ZX80 3CL
108 323656
MikeG@email.com
Yes
0


9
Jean
Marston
17-Aug-60
SomeWhere 9
SomeTown
ZY1 2BC
109 323656
JeanM@email.com
No
1


10
Iris
Chambers
18-Oct-06
SomeWhere 10
SomeTown
ZX80 3CL
110 323656
IrisC@email.com
No
0



Bookings Table



BookingID
BookingDate
BookingTime
MemberID
ActivityID
GroupID




1
03-Oct-24
10:00
2
1



2
07-Oct-24
11:00

5
2


3
21-Oct-24
09:00
1
2



4
29-Oct-24
13:00

4
7


5
05-Nov-24
12:00

3
3


6
13-Nov-24
11:00
9
1



7
17-Nov-24
10:00

4
2


8
20-Nov-24
15:00

2
6


9
15-Dec-24
16:00
6
1



10
22-Dec-24
13:00

5
1


11
09-Oct-24
12:21
7
1



12
26-Oct-24
13:00
7
2





In more advanced databases this would be an insert trigger. But I don't think access has that. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623440/ms-access-trigger

Synchronizing the NoOfLessonsBooked is not as simple as that. You will also have to take into account record deletions and updates. Some updating the data through another application might not apply the corresponding logic. And you can get out of sync very easily. Instead, I would calculate the number of lessons booked dynamically in a query.

Make sure you don't post real people's information like this; it's a GDPR violation. Then either look into triggers (don't know if Access has them). Or just run a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bookings WHERE MemberID = '...' to find how many bookings a person had.

Access 2016 introduced Data macros which are similar to triggers.

You could use an After Insert Data Macro on the booking table that updates the Member table and increments the NoOfLessonsBooked. You might also consider an Delete trigger on the booking table to subtract 1 from Member.NoOfLessonsBooked.
To create a Data macro that captures the After Insert event, use the following steps.

Open the table for which you want to capture the After Insert event. [Bookings]

On the Table tab, in the After Events group, click After Insert.


An empty data macro is displayed in the macro designer. Add the following Action blocks:
Look up A Record in Member
Where Condition = [MemberID] = [Bookings].[MemberID]
EditRecord
   SetField
            name [Member].[NoOfLessonsBooked]
            value = [Member].[NoOfLessonsBooked] + 1
End EditRecord

see this question for more details
